# How to change eclipse suggestions order and content

Tags: eclipse

I installed the Eclipse Neon but feels bad with its code suggestions.

Take the code template as an example, usually I type **main** and press <ALT> + / to show the suggestions. In the old versions, the main method template shows at the first one. However, the top N is occupied by many Main* class main, it doesn't make sense for me.

Is there any way to change it ?

- how to remove any Main* class's suggestions
- how to let the **code template** move to top

[image: eclipse suggests]

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you need, but the most approximate solution I know is that you can press CTRL+SPACE *repeatedly* to browse the content assist list. The first list Eclipse shows is the *default* proposals. But if you press CTRL+SPACE again and again, Eclipse will show a more specific list each time.

Go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content assist > Advanced`.

The upper list allows you to select (not to sort, sorry!) the contents that will show up as *default* proposals. This is where you read this unordered, unpractical list of contents. Then, if you press CTRL+SPACE again, Eclipse will show the poposals by categories. The order for these categories to show can be set by the lower list in this window: `Content assist cycling`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this will be relevant any more, but i ended up here looking exactly for this, and later found out a solution. This might be linked to a specific Eclipse version (i use Oxygen right now)
Go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content assist` and you will find an option that let you select between relevance and alphabetically.
[image: here's the screenshot]